# How do I fetch one row at the time with node-mysql / node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have some PHP code I need to port to node.js / Javascript and I dont know how to do this properly: fetching only one row at a time.

I have a query that results in a MASSIVE dataset; I only need a few of the results; but I dont know how many.

In PHP I just execute the query and then fetch row per row until the condition is met. 
php pseudo code:

```
$sql="select price, totvol from depth where.. order by price desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  //massive dataset
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and some condition) {
    do stuff until condition is met     
}
```

I dont see how I can this in node-mysql. I could add a LIMIT 1 to the sql  query and make a new query each time, but then how do I get the next row in the ordered list? Any tips would be much appreciated.

If it helps, this is the actual code:

```
$sql='';
if ($type=="bid") $sql="select price, totvol from depth where price>=$price order by price asc";
elseif ($type=="ask") $sql="select price, totvol from depth where price<=$price order by price desc";
else echo "unknown type\n";
if ($sql!='') {
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and $amount_int>0) {
        $newamount=max($row["totvol"]-$amount_int,0);
        $amount_int-=$row["totvol"];
        $sql2="update depth set totvol=$newamount where price=".$row["price"];
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or ie(mysql_error());                              
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors for grabbing too many rows with node? Memory consumption issues? I don't see why it would be so different. When you run a query from PHP, you also retrieve all rows, using `mysql_fetch_assoc` is just a way too loop them/move the internal pointer.

Comment: @bfavarettoI I havent tried actually; and it turns out you are correct; in php I should have used mysql_unbuffered_query(). Doh. So I guess it could work; but since this code is moving to a VPS with constrained memory; Id still like to optimise it.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/tree/v2.0/#streaming-query-rows

Comment: Actually; no its not quite what Im looking for. It only pauzes the flow of results. I dont see a way to stop it. Moreover it actually pauzes the db connection which I still need inside the loop. It also says there:"Additionally you may be interested to know that it is currently not possible to stream individual row columns, they will always be buffered up entirely.": Looks like I will have to use LIMIT and make ugly code :(

Comment: I see. I have never used unbuffered queries, but now that I know about them, I'll start considering that. My advice is: first, try fetching the whole resultset. If that causes resource/performance issues, use a limit, but `LIMIT 1` would be my last option. Try a higher number that retrieves a reasonable amount of results, so you'll only need to issue a new query in rare cases.

Comment: yeah I plan to fetch a few 100 or 1000 at least. Its just that the entire table currently consists of ~100K records and will grow to millions and loading all of those seems stupîd (when typically I only need the first 5-50) and a recipe for disaster.